# Need help working with Matrices in R

Tags: r, vector, matrix, parentheses

So write now I'm writing a function in R that looks at a set of vectors presented as a matrix, and two test vectors, and then checks each vector in the original set, and decides which of the two test vectors it's closer to (or neither), and then out puts the three datasets as matrices (the vectors closer to the first test, second test, and neither). I wrote another function which just looks at three vectors, and then gives as an output which vector the first vector is closer to (that's the closer function). It, and its results, are used in the new function.

Here is the code for the bigger function:

```
vectorwork <- function(mat,test1,test2){
  closer1 = ()
  closer2 = ()
  neither = ()
  y = dim(mat)[2]
  for(i in 1:(dim(mat)[1]){
    if(closer(mat[i,],test1,test2)==1){
      closer1[length(closer1)+1] = mat[i,]
    }
    else if(closer(mat[i,],test1,test2)==2){
      closer2[length(closer2)+1] = mat[i,]
    }
    else{
      neither[length(neither)+1] = mat[i,]
    }
  }
  close1 = matrix(closer1, (length(closer1)/y), y)
  close2 = matrix(closer2, (length(closer2)/y), y)
  neith = matrix(neither, (length(neither)/y), y)
print(close1,close2,neith)
}
```

I keep getting paren errors all over the code. Since I'm new to R, I'm not really sure where exactly I'm going wrong. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is unbalanced parentheses.

```
  for(i in 1:(dim(mat)[1])     {
     ^       ^   C   C   ^    <--- innermost pair
     |       B           B    <- middle pair
     A                        <- outermost one is unpaired
```

This is basic. Count!

```
  for(i in 1:(dim(mat)[1]) ) {
                           ^
                           |
                        put it in
```

The thing is, from your post ("*paren errors*") and comments ("*Error: unexpected '{' in: " for(i in 1:(dim(mat)[1]) {*"), it looks like you apparently already knew what the problem was AND you apparently already knew what line the problem was on. Given that, all you needed to do was count to three.

Here's a little trick I use when checking parentheses; as I read across, I count "1", "2" as I hit each "(". Then when I hit a ")" I subtract again, going up and down as I hit more "(" and ")". By the time I get to where it all should be closed off, *I better hit 0*.

Consider your offending line. The count has to hit zero before the "{" ! Does it?

```
  for(i in 1:(dim(mat)[1])     { 
     1       2   3   2   1     Nope. I'm short a ")".
```

This doesn't usually find the exact place to insert the missing one, but it quickly shows you definitely have a problem and then it's usually easy to find.

Comment: Heh, I'm really bad with parens... I looked it up and down eight times, and couldn't find where my mistake was. Thanks.

Comment: Start using an IDE like RStudio, which shows you matching parentheses (and actually inserts a closing one if you type an opening parenthesis).

Comment: @Roland I use Rstudio, but for me it causes as many problems as it solves for keeping parentheses and quotes balanced. It's great if you only type left to right and never need to go back to insert stuff, or want to insert an end-quote before you type an open-quote.

Answer (score 4):

One of the fundamentals of R is that it makes use of vectors. This means you can do an element-by-element comparison of two vectors with a simple `==` comparison:

```
x==a
```

So, try this instead:

```
set.seed(1)
x <- sample(1:5, 10, replace=TRUE)
a <- sample(1:5, 10, replace=TRUE)
b <- sample(1:5, 10, replace=TRUE)

sum(x==a)
[1] 1
sum(x==b)
[1] 2
```

To get your last comparison, put a logical AND operator `&` in the evaluation:

```
sum(x!=a & x!=b)
[1] 7
```

Comment: This definitely helps clean up the for loop section, but the error i'm getting is 

Error: unexpected '{' in:
"  
  for(i in 1:(dim(mat)[1]) {"

which, it would seem, leads to the rest of the errors involved. For some reason, it has a syntax (i think) problem with the start of the function. I'll use your method to clean up the for loop, though.

Comment: The line with "FOR" has 3 left parens, and 2 right parens so it might be expecting the third right paren when if finds the left curley.

Comment: Thanks, that was it. I re-wrote it from scratch, and that fixed it.